# Show edited value in aside in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, admin-on-rest

I am using react-admin for admin interface. In edit form aside i want to show edited value (just to understand how to capture form changed values, later will show data from api for those changed values). My code as follows (Simplified)

```
const Aside = ({ record }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 200, margin: '1em' }}>
        <Typography variant="h6">Student details</Typography>
        <Typography variant="body2">
        {record && (
            <Typography variant="body2">
                {//Will Show current ArrayInput values here, Name/role of current students}
            </Typography>
        )}
        </Typography>
    </div>
)};

export const MyEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit aside={<Aside />} {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <ArrayInput source="students">
                <SimpleFormIterator>
                  <TextInput source="name" /
                  <NumberInput source="role" />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
              </ArrayInput>
      </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
);
```

How to update aside onchange of ArrayInput values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React-admin uses react-final-form, which in turns uses a react Context to store the current form values.

that means that you can't access these values from outside the form (and I the aside is outside the form).

The solution is to store the current form values in a state shared by both SimpleForm and Aside (or even in the Redux store). To do so, use a [FormSpy](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/api/FormSpy) in the form, which will update the shared state when the value changes.

```
// in MyEdit.js
export const MyEdit = (props) => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState();
  return ( 
  <Edit aside={<Aside formValues={formValues} />} {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <ArrayInput source="students">
                <SimpleFormIterator>
                  <TextInput source="name" /
                  <NumberInput source="role" />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
              </ArrayInput>
         <FormSpy
             subscription={{ valid: true }}
             onChange={props => {
                 setFormValues(props.values);
             }}
          />
      </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
  );
};
```

Comment: merci beaucoup!

Comment: i get this error ""FormSpy must be used inside of a <Form> component"" however i put it inside simpleform